# payroll system in java

Tags: java, class

I am implementing a payroll system in which I need to implement a `PayrollSystem` class to add an employee to an `ArrayList` of employees and create checks for each of those said employees. I've written up the `Employee` and `Paycheck` classes, but I'm having trouble with the `PayrollSystem` class.

How do I create the `addEmployee` method? Do I pass an `Employee` object to it along with the information on that employee or is there another way?

**Employee:**

```
package payrollSystem;

public class Employee {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int ID;
    private double hourlyWage;
    private double hoursWorked;

    public Employee(String first, String last, int id, double wage, double hours) {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
        ID = id;
        hourlyWage = wage;
        hoursWorked = hours;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String first) {
        this.firstName = first;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String last) {
        this.lastName = last;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setHourlyWage(double hourlyWage) {
        this.hourlyWage = hourlyWage;
    }

    public double getHourlyWage() {
        return hourlyWage;
    }

    public void setHoursWorked(double hoursWorked) {
        this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
    }

    public double getHoursWorked() {
        return hoursWorked;
    }

    public double calcPay(double wage, double hours) {
        wage = getHourlyWage();
        hours = getHoursWorked();

        return wage * hours;
     }
}
```

**PayCheck:**

```
package payrollSystem;

public class PayCheck {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int ID;
    private double netAmount;

    public PayCheck(String first, String last, int id, double wage, double hours) {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
        ID = id;
        netAmount = wage * hours;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Paycheck issued for " + netAmount + "to " + firstName + ", "+ lastName + ", employee ID " + ID;
    }
}
```

**PayrollSystem:**

```
package payrollSystem;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PayrollSystem {
     public List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
     public String companyName;

     PayrollSystem(String company) {
         companyName = company;
     }

     void addEmployee(Employee a) {
         employees.add(a);
     }

     void getHoursWorked(double hrs) {
         this.a.getHoursWorked();
     }

     void issueCheck() {
         double checkAmount = this.a.calcPay(a.getHoursWorked(), a.getHourlyWage());

         PayCheck check = new PayCheck(a.getFirstName(), a.getLastName(),  a.getID(), a.getHoursWorked(), a.getHourlyWage());

         check.toString();
     }
}
```

Comment: `PayCheck` constructor should just take in an `Employee` object, since all of its values are from the `Employee` class anyway. Pointless to strip 5 parameters from the same kind of object every time you're calling the constructor, when you could just pass in the object and strip the parameters inside the constructor once.

Comment: Also `calcPay()` doesn't use its parameters for anything, so they are pointless to have in the first place.

Comment: Also `getHoursWorked()` and `issueCheck()` need to get an `Employee` object as their parameter. `a` isn't defined in either one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an `addEmployee()` method. As long as somewhere you create the employee, and then pass it into your payRoll class.

Would look like this, assuming you have a `List` of Employees :

```
public void addEmployee(Employee employee){
    employees.add(employee);
}
```

In your `main` you could then just go (assuming myEmployee is an Employee Object):

```
PayrollSystem payrollSystem = new PayRollSystem();
payrollSystem.addEmployee(new Employee("John", "Smith", 1, wage, hours)); // Way 1
payrollSystem.addEmployee(myEmployee); // Way 2
```

The Employee Object will contain all the information of the Employee. So when that Object is passed in, all the information will come with it. That allows you to fetch all the Employees from the payrollSystem, or use internal methods to perform actions on them.

Comment: would you say that creating an employee object in the test class and passing it to the method through something like ...
 [code]
Employee a = new Employee("john","sample", 0, 15.50, 30.75);
payrollSystem.addEmployee(a); [code]

Comment: Yes thats what you can do. Create an Employee like that, and then you can just `payrollSystem.addEmployee(a)`